# Bodies not being inserted in resolution tree

Tags: c++, box2d

Something weird is going on with my box2d application. Everything worked fine, but for no apparent reason forces are now not interacting with dynamic bodies (havent tested kinematic). world.getBodyCount() returns the correct number of bodies, world.Step() is being called each frame with the right arguments, gravity is properly set both on the world and the objects, and yet those bodies will not change position even when I manually apply forces to them. My only clue is both world.getTreeHeight() and world.GetTreeBalance() returning 0, so I guess the objects are not being inserted in the resolution tree. Does anybody know why not? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the bodies being created in a non-awake, non-active state. I would swear that I didn't need to set them as awake AND active before, but in any case, hope it helps someone.